# How to make JSLint tolerate a leading semi-colon?

Tags: javascript, jslint

The continuous integration software I am using runs JavaScript files through JSLint and complains if they fail (using default JSLint settings it appears).

I've always prepended a `;` to the start of my jQuery plugins, so concatenating them doesn't lead to something like this...

#### common.js

I don't have access to this file, and can't enforce a semi colon at the end.

```
var abc = function() {
    alert(arguments[0]);
}
```

#### plugin.js

This is my file that is concatenated with `common.js`. It is appended straight to the end of `common.js`.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.somePlugin = function() {}
})(jQuery);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/nrdQH/) of the problem this can cause.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/t58GB/) of the solution (leading semi-colon of my plugin).

However, JSLint complains with...

> #### Error:
>
> Problem at line 1 character 1: Unexpected space between
>   '(begin)' and ';'.
>
> `;(function($) {`
>
> Problem at line 1 character 1: Expected ';' at column 5, not column 1.
>
> `;(function($) {`
>
> Problem at line 1 character 2: Missing space between ';' and '('.
>
> ...

I tried using a bang operator (`!`) instead, and a few other alternatives, but JSLint still complained.

What can I do to get this safety net *and* pass JSLint?

Comment: Perhaps a better concatenator is in order.  What are you using to smush your js files together?

Comment: @Paul I am not sure, this has been set up for a while and I am a relatively recent employee here.

Comment: If your file is being added to common.js, how do you not have access to common.js?

Comment: @Paul Something in the process is concatenating them. There is a team of developers elsewhere (who have setup `common.js`) and I am only working on front end code for this portion of the business.

Comment: For what it's worth, I sent Crockford an email this morning with a reference to this thread and he responded, asking me to try it.  So I think he updated jslint based on what I'm seeing here:  https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/commit/a2935fbda12c4c2de57de1761d4a50c166a5b3ce

Comment: @Shane That was *really* constructive and useful. So bad you don't get more up-votes I don't know why. I have seen issues like this in JSLint grow into religious wars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Patch JSLint to not mind.  Everyone will benefit.

Comment: Whilst that *would* be a good option, this is only my 3rd week here and the people that could authorise this are 800kms away. I don't think that option would fly.

Comment: @alex, while I think that patching JSLint would not be a good idea, the fact that authority resides 800 km away sounds like the perfect situation for innovation on your part.

Comment: @Paul: I'm curious why you think patching JSLint would be bad?  I meant, "and contribute the change back upstream."

Comment: @Ned, ok, I thought you meant that he should just insert some code at his company quietly :)  I agree that adding a param to ignore his problem would be a useful contribution.

Comment: Whilst this answer won't help *me*, it is probably the best advice :)

Comment: See my comment above, looks like Crockford did that himself this morning.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you put the `;` on a line by itself, or put some other syntactically valid but meaningless statement like this:

```
"begin plugin";
(function() { // etc
```

EDIT: what about using `void`:

```
void("begin plugin");
(function() { // etc

//or

void(
(function() { /* your code */ })()
);
```

EDIT 2: what about some variation on this:

```
if (console && console.log) { // or if (false)?
  console.log("Begining plugin definition");
}
(function { // etc
```

Comment: JSLint expects the string to be assigned (I tried that) and the newline trick, whilst sounding promising, didn't work either. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @alex - OK then, I'm down to just inserting a statement that looks to JSLint like it does something but really it doesn't, like `if (1>2) alert("Take that JSLint!");` - and presumably you've already thought of that but don't want to do it because it's ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a flippant answer, but your html can probably do this:

```
<script src="common.js"></script>
<script>;</script>
<script src="plugin.js"></script>
```

Or if you don't like the inline script on the second line, make a file called `semicolon.js` and, well, you know....

Sorry if this is ridiculous, but JSLint *does not like a plain old empty statement on a line by itself*.  Somewhat unfortunate.  Oh well.

BTW awesome fiddle.  Seeing that alert run because of the missing semicolon after the var declaration of the function was, like, wow what do you know? That function got called as it should!  Very interesting.

Comment: Interesting solution, but remember the files are being concatenated, i.e. one file. :P

Comment: Oh, so you have to subject common.js to JSLint as well then, without being able to edit it?  If that is the case, you need to either (1) break that and get permission to only subject plugin.js to JSLint, or (2) Get your company to allow you uncheck "Tolerate messy whitespace".  I also like the patch idea.  Send this question to Crockford and get his opinion! :-)

Comment: I get the feeling Crockford won't want to hear anyone's opinions except his own regarding JavaScript :P